# How to hide xposed presence for other apps?

Tags: xposed-framework

I need some way to hide `XposedBridge.jar` from other apps. In this case it's for Snapchat. It doesn't let me log in because of the `XposedBridge.jar` presence. Keep in mind that **I can't reinstall xposed.**

Thanks!

Comment: Install [Root Cloak Xposed module](http://www.gammerson.com/2015/11/how-to-use-snapchat-on-rooted-device.html) seems to work

Comment: @beeshyams it hides root presence, not Xposed presence.

Comment: But that post linked suggested snapchat running- things may have changed

Comment: And if Snapchat can't see root, it should work as claimed in the blog, unless it goes looking for the `.jar` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ***Sudohide***

by *SudoCode755*

Its a continuation of *FatMinMin's* **MinMinHide**.

With this module you can hide applications from each other. It was buggy in the beginning, but it works great for me.

---

**How to use**

To hide an app from another, simply choose the target app and then select the apps you want hidden from it. Don't forget to hit ***save***.

---

**Photo**
[image: Photo1]

---

**Reference links:**

- [Xposed Repository](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.sudocode.sudohide)
- [Github source](https://github.com/SudoCode755/SudoHide)
- [XDA support](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/mod-sudohide-prevent-apps-detected-apps-t3384559)

Comment: How does this work for Xposed itself. Have an App that scans for Xposed and doesn't work if installed. I could not hide Xposed with this.

Comment: unfortunately some app developers are catching on and detecting the XposedBridge.. trying to workout a way around this